# Arduino does not run with high values

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have the code below (cod01) that I need to convert into code for Arduino (cod02). It deals with the Eratosthenes Sieve algorithm (finding prime numbers from an upper limit). The cod01 works perfectly and has already been tested with values above 1000000 and always runs. I converted it to Arduino but it only works until 1768. I need it to work until 2000, can someone help me?

```
//cod01
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 7
 
int main(){
  int i,j;
  int limite;
  char ehprimo[MAX];
  int cont=0;

  for(i=2;i<MAX;i++) ehprimo[i]=1;
  limite = (int)sqrt(MAX);
  for(i=2;i<=limite;i++){
    if(ehprimo[i]){
      for(j=i*i;j<MAX;j=j+i)
        ehprimo[j] = 0;
    }
  }

  for(i=2;i<MAX;i++){
    if(ehprimo[i]){
      printf("%d\t",i);
    }
  }
return 0;
}
```

.

```
//cod02
#define MAX 2000
  
  int i,j;
  int limite;
  char ehprimo[MAX];
  int cont=0;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  for(i=2;i<MAX;i++) ehprimo[i]=1;
  limite = (int)sqrt(MAX);
  for(i=2;i<=limite;i++){
    if(ehprimo[i]){
      for(j=i*i;j<MAX;j=j+i)
        ehprimo[j] = 0;
    }
  }

   for(i=2;i<MAX;i++){
    if(ehprimo[i]){
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(i);
    }
  }
  
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it only works to 1768?

Comment: `int` in arduino is a 16-bit type so it can't represent huge values such as 1000000

Comment: Defining the cod02 MAX global variable in 1768 the code works perfectly, above that it no longer works.

Comment: @phuclv In arduino (cod02) I can not reach at least 2000?

Comment: What happens when you use the size that "doesn't work"? Does the program crash before calculating anything? Does it start to output and then fail? You'll need to narrow this down a bit. If you comment out the calculation and output in your setup function and replace it with a single `Serial.Print("It Works!")'` does it work?

Comment: @wdn `i*i` will overflow if `i > sqrt(32767)`. And it's a very bad idea to call `sqrt(MAX)` in embedded systems. The math library alone will consume a lot of ROM space

Comment: Programming obsolete 8 bit MCUs is hard - it requires a lot of in-depth knowledge about C and how C code translates to machine code. It's not a PC where you can just merrily  hack away without knowing anything about what goes on between the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your codes simply requires to much RAM.

The Arduino Uno (with an ATmega328P µC) only has 2048 Byte SRAM.

If you reserve 2000 Byte with the lines

```
#define MAX 2000
char ehprimo[MAX];
```

There is not enough left for the stack and the Arduino Framework.

You must either reduce your memory consumption or choose a µC with more SRAM.